# Microsoft-Cognitive error 403

Tags: websocket

We have a problem with this service

NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?format=simple&language=es-ES&Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=ee767f0d029749b3ab2fd001aa3845e1&X-ConnectionId=1376A7C589404E74990E605745A703F5

We tried to connect and received an error, we use SDK Speech.Browser.Sdk.ts

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an active subscription for the Bing Services?  If not, you can try a free trial at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/.  When you're ready to go live, you can purchase a service using your Azure subscription.

Comment: Yes, I have a valid subscription. The service is the problem

Comment: I should have looked closer at your URL as the syntax is incorrect.  You've placed the subscription key in the URL and now it's been compromised by posting it to SO.  You should generate a new key and delete this one as soon as possible.

There are two steps to using the REST API:
Get an access token
Call the REST endpoint and include the access token.

See here for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech/getstarted/getstarted-curl